# Rails FactoryGirl duplicate key value violates unique constraint when changing the primary key attribute for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here with this test?

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "Rep", type: :feature do
  scenario "has a Manager and a Region" do
    rep = FactoryGirl.create(:rep)
    expect(rep.boss.email).to eq("first.last@email.com")
    expect(rep.region.name).to eq("NAT")
  end
end
```

Given this class for Region

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = "lid"
  has_many :reps
end
```

I have changed the primary key for region to reference the column `lid`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :rep do
    lid 1
    email 'first.last@email.com'
    association :boss, strategy: :build
    association :region, factory: :region, strategy: :build
  end

  factory :boss, class: Rep do
    lid 2
    email 'rep.manager@email.com'
    manager true
    association :region, factory: :region, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

Now when the associative `region` in a factory is built it is causing a uniqueness validation on the region.

I use these ids called legacy ids (lid) that come from another system and I use them as primary keys (database migrations are setup to handle them ok).

I can build other associations that are unique to this app so have the standard 'id' field

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :region do
    lid 10
    name 'NAT'
  end
end
```

All I want is both the `rep` and the `boss` to belong to the same `region` and so when I build a `rep` factory it comes with a `boss` and `region` association.

Hopefully it is just something so stupid I am not considering :confused:

```
rspec spec spec/features/reps/have_managers.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Reps belong to a manager
     Failure/Error: rep = FactoryGirl.create(:rep)

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_regions_on_lid"
       DETAIL:  Key (lid)=(10) already exists.
       : INSERT INTO "regions" ("lid", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "lid"
     # ./spec/features/reps/have_managers.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::UniqueViolation:
     #   ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_regions_on_lid"
     #   DETAIL:  Key (lid)=(10) already exists.
     #   ./spec/features/reps/have_managers.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

so far I have gotten away with turning the `region_id null false flag` off and making the `belongs_to optional` so that I can just comment out the region association and ignore it for now

Comment: You should generate unique `lid`s dynamically in your factories.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you have figured this out since, but for the sake of covering this you have some overlapping going on in your factories. Since the boss is a rep, you do not want to associate the boss factory with the rep factory, otherwise you end up with duplicate entries of anything that overlaps. Instead you may consider using a trait:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :rep, class: Rep do
    sequence(:lid) { |n| n }
    sequence(:email) { |e| "first.last#{e}@email.com" }
    association :region, factory: :region

    trait :boss do 
      manager true
    end
  end
end
```

Then when you want to create/build these, you can use something like this:

```
let(:rep) { create(:rep) }
let(:boss) { create(:rep, traits: [:boss]) }
```